# Apache2 server not recognizing text/css files for expire/compression

Tags: compression, apache-2.2

I'm trying to add two things:

```
ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 day"
```

and

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

but in either case it does not show up compressed or have a later expiration date.  I used Firebug to check, and cleared the cache to make sure.  The mime type is in there.  Thanks.

Edit:

Ive also added the mime type manually but it doesn't change anything:

```
AddType text/css css
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess in this case would be that your Apache is serving your CSS files as something other than `text/css`. My analogous configuration lines in both cases include a lot more types:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
```

Try putting some other MIME types in the configuration and see if they get compressed/expired properly.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like some other stuff gets compressed, but not text/css (or javascript, but i figure it's the same issue).  On Firebug it definitely sends it as text/css though.